# If Statements with radio buttons with CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do you perform an if statement inside of a form_radio element with code igniter?

My goal is to get whether or not the user will allow personal messages from other members and want the correct radio button loaded. So options would be Yes (value of 0) or No (value of 1)

This is what I tried and have come up with a syntax error but I'm not even sure I'm doing it correctly.

```
<div class="input">
    <?php echo form_label((form_radio('pmusers', '0', if ($user_settings[0]->members_can_pm == 0))) . 'Yes', 'pmusers'); ?>
   <?php echo form_label((form_radio('pmusers', '1')) . 'No', 'pmusers'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/xtremer/public_html/kowmanager/application/views/user_settings.php on line 21

Comment: You have put If inside echo, didn't close the echo.

Comment: How do I do that with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do the check inline. Also, universally, 0 = NO and 1 = YES

```
if($user_settings[0]->members_can_pm == 1){//can PM
    $canPM = 1;
    $cantPM = 0;
}else{
    $canPM=0;
    $cantPM=1;
}
echo form_label((form_radio('pmusers', '0',$canPM, 'pmusers')).'Yes','pmusers');
echo form_label((form_radio('pmusers', '0',$cantPM, 'pmusers')).'No','pmusers');
```

Comment: But that would only show 1 radio button. It would still need to show two the yes and the no with the labels with them. That code only shows 1 radio and no input